# OL 3.13.0 to 4.2.0 and ol.Map.unByKey

Tags: openlayers

In the below function the GlobalMap.unByKey(popupKey); call makes error with most recent OL (no more unByKey on ol.Map objects).
I wonder how I could change this line. 
Should I also change the way the listener is added ?

```
    var popupKey = '';
    var managePopup = function(value){
        if(value === 'off'){
            overlay.hide();
            GlobalMap.removeOverlay(overlay);
            GlobalMap.unByKey(popupKey);
        }else if(value === 'on'){
            interact.manageActiveInteraction();
            GlobalMap.addOverlay(overlay);
            popupKey = GlobalMap.on('singleclick', function(evt){initiatePopup(evt);});
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

The `unByKey()` method has been removed from `ol.Observable` instances from v4.0.0.
check this [change log](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/6f54f6c1133e0a0bba7099736b0b413b8a7253d2/changelog/v4.0.0.md#removal-of-deprecated-methods)

Answer (score 1):

OK I just have to use  `ol.Observable.unByKey(popupKey);` instead.

I first did not understood that it could be called directly